# Is cup product of cycle classes on Noetherian regular excellent scheme compatible with intersection

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a Noetherian regular integral excellent scheme. Let $Y$ and $Z$ be algebraic cycles of  codimension $c$ and $d$ on $\mathcal{X}$.
Let $n$ be a positive integer invertible on $\mathcal{X}$. Assume $Y$ intersects $Z$ properly and define $Y\cap Z$ by Serre's Tor formula. Do we have
$$Cl(Y)\smallsmile Cl(Z)= Cl(Y\cap Z)$$ 
Where $Cl(Y)$ is the cycle class of $Y$ in $H^{2c}_{|Y|}(\mathcal{X},\mathbb{Z}/n(c))$
 (By Gabber's purity theorem, it can be defined as chapter 4 2.2.10 in SGA 4 1/2).
By  Remark  2.3.9 chapter 4, in Deligne's SGA 4 1/2, the claim holds for smooth varieties over algebraic closed fields. I think by localization, it should work for cycles whose supports are locally complete intersection closed subscheme.

Comment: There is no need for excellency nor regularity (if we reformulate this properly). This follows from Section 3 (applied to Example 2.11) in arXiv:1909.01332 for instance.